How do I limit Windows 11 desktop search to either filenames or file contents?
When I am doing a windows desktop search, sometimes I wish to search file names, and sometimes file contents, but never both at once. How do I limit my search to file names only?  How do I limit my search to (local) file contents only?

Does this answer your question? How do I limit a Microsoft desktop search to files on my computer?

Remove one of the duplicate questions.

In File Explorer, you can use syntax like:

FileName:myFile searches file names only
Foldername:myFolder searches folder names only
Name:someName searches folder or file names (may also search properties like song name)
content:"hello world" searches file contents only

These can be combined in the search bar, like filename:myFile content:"hello world" to require both parts to match, or filename:myFile OR content:"hello world" for only one.
For more examples and properties, take a look through this link to see the rest of the Advanced Query Syntax

Alternatively, if you meant searching from the windows start menu, then you can use a similar-looking syntax to search for local file names, but it does not search their contents:

Documents: myFile searches file names in your Documents folder. Same for other libraries like Photos:
Folders: myFolder searches folder names everywhere


note: the file explorer property searches generally require that windows has already indexed the files, or else it will run slowly. It's usually only an issue for files you just created
